# Mapstruct kotlin and @Named annotation

Tags: android, kotlin, mapstruct

I'm converting some pet project from java to kotlin and stuck with some problem that can't solve. In java all compile fine but after convertation to Kotlin doesn't want....

```java
...
import org.mapstruct.Mapper
import org.mapstruct.Mapping
import org.mapstruct.Named
...

@Mapper(unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.ERROR)
interface EffectMapper {

    @Mapping(source = "icon", target = "icon", qualifiedByName = ["convertIcon"])
    fun toDS(effectDTO: EffectDTO): EffectDS

    fun toDSarr(effectDTOArrayList: ArrayList<EffectDTO>): ArrayList<EffectDS>

    @Named("convertIcon")
    fun convertIcon(obj: String?): ByteArray? {
        return if (obj != null) {
            Base64.decode(obj, Base64.DEFAULT)
        } else {
            null
        }
    }

    companion object {
        val MAPPER = Mappers.getMapper(EffectMapper::class.java)
    }
}
```

Gradle return error

```
 error: Can't generate mapping method from non-iterable type to iterable type.
    public abstract byte[] convertIcon(@org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable()
```

and

```
Can't map property "java.lang.String icon" to "byte[] icon". Consider to declare/implement a mapping method: "byte[] map(java.lang.String value)".
    @org.mapstruct.Mapping(source = "icon", target = "icon", qualifiedByName = {"convertIcon"})
```

and

```
Can't map property "java.lang.String effect" to "one.codium.funart.DataStructure.effect.Effect effect". Consider to declare/implement a mapping method: "one.codium.funart.DataStructure.effect.Effect map(java.lang.String value)".
    public abstract one.codium.funart.DataStructure.EffectDS toDS(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
```

finally it was done by this way

```java
@Mapper(unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.ERROR, uses = [EffectMapperImpl::class])
interface EffectMapper {

    fun toDS(effectDTO: EffectDTO): EffectDS

    fun toDSarr(effectDTOArrayList: ArrayList<EffectDTO>): ArrayList<EffectDS>

    companion object {
        val MAPPER: EffectMapper = Mappers.getMapper(EffectMapper::class.java)
    }
}

object EffectMapperImpl {

    fun convertIcon(obj: String?): ByteArray? {
        return if (obj != null) {
            Base64.decode(obj, Base64.DEFAULT)
        } else {
            null
        }
    }

    fun toEffect(s: String): Effect {
        return Effect(s)
    }
}
```

Thank you @Filip

Comment: How does this work since you don't point "icon" field to use function "convertIcon" for conversion?

Comment: I tried your last way, but it still doesn't work. The EffectMapperImpl was not being imported by Mapper#uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are seeing is due to the fact that the `convertIcon` method is not recognized as a default method in the `EffectMapper` interface.

Even if you use `@JvmDefault` it won't work due to [KT-25960](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-25960). I would suggest that you extract the `convertIcon` method into a public static method in another class and then use it via `Mapper#uses`

Comment: public static class should be Java class, or could be Kotlin. Could you provide a little bit code please.

Answer (score 6):

I am using Kotlin 1.3.71-release-431 and it works fine with @JvamDefault, so you just need to make your conversion method (toEffect) static in (java).

```
Mapping(source = "sourceFiledName", target = "destinationFiledName", qualifiedByName = ["converterMethod"])
interface EffectMapper {
  fun toDS(effectDTO: EffectDTO): EffectDS
  
  fun toDSarr(effectDTOArrayList: ArrayList<EffectDTO>): ArrayList<EffectDS>
  
  companion object {
     @JvmStatic
     @Named("converterMethod")
     fun toEffect(s: String): Effect {
        return Effect(s)
      }
  }
}
```